# Create timeline using c# with TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayout, timeline

I am trying to create a timeline with a tablelayoutpanel and I am almost there. There are two things missing which I cant seem to figure out.

1. First of all I would like to know if there is any way for a control to span half a column (cell)?
2. Then I would like to know how to include multiple controls in one cell.

If anyone could supply example code with explanation that would be great. Let me know if anything is unclear or if I need to post some more code.

This is my code so far:

```
    public void Init(List<DateModel> dates)
    {
        Table.Controls.Clear();
        Table.RowCount = 10;
        for (int i = 1; i <= Table.RowCount; i++)
            Table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 10));
        Table.ColumnCount = 38;
        for (int i = 1; i <= Table.ColumnCount; i++)
            Table.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        Table.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        Controls.Add(Table);
        SetUpGrid();
        SetUp(dates);
    }

    public void SetUp(List<DateModel> dates)
    {
        var row = 1;
        foreach (var date in dates)
        {
            AddEntry(date.Day, row, 0, 1, Color.White, Color.Black, false);
            for (int i = 0; i < date.LogEntries.Count; i++)
                try
                {
                    AddEntry(string.Format("", row, GetColumnIndex(date.LogEntries[i].Start), GetColumnIndex(date.LogEntries[i].Stop)  date.LogEntries[i].Start, date.LogEntries[i].Start - date.LogEntries[i].Stop, Color.White, Color.Black, false, date.LogEntries[i]);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            row++;
        }
    }

    private void AddEntry(string text, int row, int col, int columnSpan, Color foreColor, Color backColor, 
        bool border, LogEntry entry = null)
    {
        var lbl = new Label
        {
            Text = text,
            AutoSize = false,
            AutoEllipsis = true,
            ForeColor = foreColor,
            BackColor = backColor,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            BorderStyle = border ? BorderStyle.FixedSingle : BorderStyle.None,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft, 
            Tag = entry,
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand
        };


        // Perhaps I need to check if a cell is empty? 


        lbl.Click += new EventHandler(EditEntry);            
        Table.Controls.Add(lbl, col, row);
        Table.SetColumnSpan(lbl, columnSpan);
    }

    public void SetUpGrid()
    {
        AddEntry(string.Format("Today:"), 0, 0, 1, Color.White, Color.Black, false);
        AddEntry("| 05:00", 0, 1, 2, Color.White, Color.Black, false);
        // And so on.. All the way to 23:00
    }
```

Comment: 1: No.  2: Use a panel.  This is not a good idea, UI gets pokey with this many controls.  Use a proper grid control, like DataGridView.

Comment: I do not like layout panels because of the limited number of properties.  Always get into a situation when I can't do something like "span a half a column". I build my own layout panel by using the standard panel object a then have one main panel and add an array of child panels.

Comment: "First of all I would like to know if there is any way for a control to span half a column (cell)?"  Yes?...split that column into two columns of equal size.  Now you can make it span "halfway".

Comment: @Idle_Mind How do I that then? :)

Comment: Consider using MSChart.